# Unsupported format in function medianBlur for USB Camera (Python/RaspberryPI/OpenCV)

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I'm creating a test program that would allow the program to find any circles in the image after camera capture, but for some reason, if I used the data from the camera into any function (for this one, medianBlur), an error would return.

**error: (-210:Unsupported format or combination of formats)  in function 'medianBlur'**

Here is the code for the test program:

```
# initialize the camera
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, image = cam.read()
img = cv2.medianBlur(ret,5)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)
cv2.imshow('SnapshotTest',cimg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyWindow('SnapshotTest')
cv2.imwrite('/home/pi/Desktop/lol.jpg',image)
cam.release()
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem lies here

```py
ret, image = cam.read()
img = cv2.medianBlur(ret,5)
```

You are applying `medianBlur`to `ret` value instead of `image`.

Use

```py
img = cv2.medianBlur(image, 5)
```

Comment: Yeah, I already tried that, a different error occurs along the lines of 
```File "cap2.py", line 6, in <module>
    img = cv2.medianBlur(image,5)
TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'src'```

Comment: Is the value of `ret` `False`? It could be possible that there is no image. And therefore the type of `img` is `None` and not `cv::UMat`

Comment: Nope, there is data. A bunch of matrixes show up when I print the image variable.

Comment: check the type of image. what does `print(type(image))` show?

Comment: It's a class tuple

Comment: so there lies the problem. why is it a tuple? Is there something being done between `cam.read()` and `medianBlur`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205214/discussion-between-itmaster-and-abhilb).